# Куда ссылаются переменные родительских классов проинициализированные объектами дочерних?

Tags: java, ооп, полиморфизм

Помогите разобраться, я знаю, что здесь должна быть ошибка, но хочу собрать до конца пазл в голове, почему именно она возникает?
Есть два класса:

```
public class Smartphone {
    private String type;

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Smartphone{" +
                "type='" + type + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}

public class ObjectTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object o = new Smartphone();
        Smartphone s = o; // ОШИБКА
    }
}
```

Вопросы:

1. верно ли утверждение, что ошибка возникает, потому что через переменную родительского класса мы можем получить только объект этого (родительского) класса?
2. если да (в чем крайне сомневаюсь), то почему при вызове `o.toString()` вызывается переопределенный метод класса Smartphone?
3. если нет и мы, через переменную родительского класса, получаем объект Smartphone, то почему тогда здесь ошибка `Smartphone s = o;`? Знаю, что через переменные родителя можно обращаться только к методам определенным в самом родителе и их переопределенным версиям, но почему нельзя передать значение переменной типа Object в переменную Smartphone, если она ссылается на объект типа Smartphone?

Comment: можно вот так `Smartphone s = (Smartphone) o;`

Comment: переменная и тип переменной - это как бумажка с адресом, на которой написано что мол, по такому то адресу лежит объект определенного типа. Вы можете иметь 100 переменных, которые указывают на один и тот же объект в памяти.

Comment: `Smartphone s = o; // ОШИБКА` возникает только потому, что компилятор не разбирается, на какой конкретно объект будет указывать переменная при запуске програмы, потому компилятор вам сообщает, что самостоятельно такую операцию он делать не будет. Но вы можете привести типы самостоятельно вот так `Smartphone s = (Smartphone)o;`

Answer (score 0):

Переменная родительского класса может содержать ссылку на объект дочернего класса.
Объявляя переменную определённого типа мы говорим компилятору, что надо проверять, что через эту переменную можно делать с объектом только то, что можно делать с объектом указанного типа.
Если мы точно знаем, что сейчас переменная указывает на экземпляр дочернего класса, мы должны сообщить об этом компилятору, указав настоящий тип объекта:
`(Smartphone) o;`

Компилятор проверяет выполнение правила, что переменная может ссылаться только на объект того же типа или подтипа этого типа. Как он узнаёт тип объекта: из типа переменной, которая указывает на объект, или из типа возвращаемого значения метода, возвращающего объект, или из кастинга.

Comment: Друзья, спасибо за ответы, про кастинг я знаю) но хочется понять именно с точки зрения компилятора, как он мыслит в этой ситуации и почему видит ошибку в этом...

Alexander Ivanov, @tym32167 , я правильно понимаю, что проблема кроется в том, что именно во время компиляции, компилятор не знает на какой именно объект ссылается переменная "o" и с любыми объектами через эту переменную, он работает как с Object, а уже в рантайме, благодаря механизму динамического связывания происходит вызов нужных переопределенных методов, как например в нашем случае o.toString() вызывет метод класса Smartphone?

Comment: Alexander Ivanov, @tym32167 И компилятору нужно явно сообщать (с помощью привидения типов) на какой именно объект мы ссылаемся, только потому что динамическое связываение происходит только в рантайме?